# Transferring Pdf files from Local folder to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, data-migration

I have a monthly activity where i get hundreds of PDF files in a folder and i need to transfer those to an AWS server . Currently i do this activity manually . But i need to automate this process of transfer  of all pdf files form my local folder to a specific folder in AWS . 
Also this process takes a lot of time ( approx 5 hours for 500 pdf files) . Is there a way to spped up the process?

Answer (score 1):

While doing the copy from `local` to `AWS` you must be using some tool like `winSCP` or any SSH client, so you could automate the same using the script.

```
scp [-r] /you/pdf/dir youruser@aswhost:/home/user/path/
```

If you want to do it with speed, you could run multiple `scp` `command` in parallel of multiple terminal and may `split files` while creating to some logical grouped directories.

Comment: we are doing a simple copy form local folder and pasting in aws folder by opening it in mstsc

Comment: doen't matter, you could simple use `scp` I have suggested in put it in `batch` file and could trigger the command or even could `automate and schedule` it.

Comment: Can you tell me the complete process?

Answer (score 0):

You can zip the files and transfer them. After transfer unzip the files. 
Or else write a program which iterates over  all files in your folder and uploads files to s3 using S3 api methods.

Comment: Can you guide me through the complete process?